# Which vscode API provide functionality like "Find all reference", and allowed implemented in my vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am now working out a plugin which shows events information of static code analysis defect. My ideal user interface to present looks like "Find all reference", (please refer below picture). It supposed shows the list of event in right panel, and while click on one of event, it will move focus of source code panel on left.

[click on "find all reference" in context menu will display like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzhLA.png)

But the problem now is that I can't find which existing vscode API I can use or find any useful information by google or from VSCode extension development document. 
   Could any one help?

Answer (score 2):

The best place to learn about available APIs is the [vscode namespace API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api) page. There is a `ReferenceProvider` class which might be what you are looking for.